# CSS Navigation (Browser Issues)

Tags: css, navigation, cross-browser

I am at a loss, I have redone this navigation at least four times. At first I couldn't get it going in Safari/Chrome, Now It works everywhere but Opera.

I have validated the page (html & CSS) and everything checked out, the only html errors were minor and can't be changed because that is a third party tracking code that has to stay on page. I apologize for the crazy css - I am self taught and my web-design has come secondary to running the business. I would really appreciate any help :)

CSS for the Navigation starts on line 273

Link to problem page -

http://www.orlandominivacations.com/testing_new_header_semi_working.html

Comment: please post the relevant css and html here. also what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: What doesn't work in Opera exactly?

Comment: The top navigation on the green bar, I'll have the original question updated with relevant code. I left it out just because I figured it would be easier for you all to look at the source.

Comment: I believe the CSS is too long to add to the question, it will not save.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you were trying to accomplish with the `content` property on lines 281 and 466 of your CSS, but when I removed those two lines, it worked in Opera.  The content property can only be used in psuedo elements `:before` and `:after`.  See [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) for more information.

Comment: It controls a section on another page, but it's an easy workaround - thank you so much!

Comment: Also, I don't mean to be overly critical, but "Attraction" is spelled wrong on the "Attraction Info" link.  One of the first things I noticed when the page loaded. edit: so is "View Cart".

Comment: Yeah, it's a dummy page, no spell check run yet. thanks though :)